# What is the random number generator that Armadillo uses?

Tags: c++, r, random, rcpp, armadillo

I am using the random number generator from the Armadillo C++ library from R. Armadillo allows high-perfomance computation of matrices and vectors.   However, I can't see which random number generator it is actually implementing.

What is the random number generator that Rcpp Armadillo uses exactly?

Comment: Depending on what random function you're using, Armadillo uses either  a uniform distribution or a Gaussian distribution for its RNG.

Comment: @birryree I meant which algorithm does it use. Is it a linear congruential generator or mersenne twister or something else?

Comment: @JonnyHenly Thank you. Which library is it referring to in the C++11 case?  And is the system library RNG std:rand()?

Comment: @JonnyHenly "it seems as though RcppArmadillo uses the RNG from R as a fallback " Is that in the docs somewhere?

Comment: @JonnyHenly Please make that an answer. It is entirely correct, documented and there are [lots of examples at the RcppGallery](http://gallery.rcpp.org).

Comment: There is one added aspect _beyond what is in the Armadillo documentation_:  We actually plug in the R RNGs because that is what Rcpp does otherwise do.

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel I didn't realize you're one of the authors and the maintainer of RcppArmadillo, you can probably write up a better answer than mine and I'll remove my answer.

Comment: It is a little messy and needs a bit of cleanup.  See [this comment in RcppArmadilloConfig.h](https://github.com/RcppCore/RcppArmadillo/blob/master/inst/include/RcppArmadilloConfig.h#L70-L74) -- what I just referred to is optional.  Let's work this out, maybe by adding code to your answer.  We could turn this into an Rcpp Gallery piece too.

Comment: Want me to make my answer a community wiki?

Comment: No your answer is great. I upvoted and edited.

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel Does this mean std:rand() is in fact never used by default?

Comment: Precisely that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Depending on whether RcppArmadillo was compiled for the C++98 standard (currently the default) or for C++11 (optional), two different RNGs may be used. [...] For C++98, the system library RNG is used. It may have poor performance, particularly on older versions of Windows. For C++11, the RNG included in its library is used. - [RcppArmadillo Documentation](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RcppArmadillo/RcppArmadillo.pdf#page.4)

*"For C++98, the system library RNG is used."* - The system library RNG is `std::rand()`, although it seems as though RcppArmadillo uses the RNG from R as a fallback (when C++11 is not selected so the C++11-based RNG is unavailable) which avoids using the older C++98-based `std::rand()`.<sup>1</sup>

*"For C++11, the RNG included in its library is used."* - This is referring to the C++11 `<random>` library.

On the other hand, also consider [this comment in RcppArmadilloForward.h](https://github.com/RcppCore/RcppArmadillo/blob/master/inst/include/RcppArmadilloForward.h#L41-L44):

```
// using this define makes the R RNG have precedent over both the
// C++11-based RNG provided by Armadillo, as well as the C++98-based
// fallback.
//
// One can use the C++11-based on by commenting out the following
// #define and also selecting C++11 (eg via src/Makevars* or the
// DESCRIPTION file) and/or defining #define-ing ARMA_USE_CXX11_RNG
#define ARMA_RNG_ALT         RcppArmadillo/Alt_R_RNG.h
```

which turns on the R RNGs as an engine for RcppArmadillo.

---

<sup>1</sup> [R-bloggers | RcppArmadillo 0.4.450.1.0](https://www.r-bloggers.com/rcpparmadillo-0-4-450-1-0/)

Comment: Thank you. It looks like the docs need updating in the light of your answer.

Comment: Pull requests are always welcome.  I [filed an issue](https://github.com/RcppCore/RcppArmadillo/issues/117).  Note that the DESCRIPTION file tells you to report bug there rather than here.